# Office Outlook 2016 (32-bit) text box and button heights not displaying correctly - Windows 10 (64-bit)

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook, 64-bit, 32-bit

The text box and button height in the new email window in Office Outlook 2016 does not display correctly. Please see image attached. Shouldn't the text boxes on the right have the same height as the buttons (From, To, Cc) on the left?

Is this a compatibility problem?

I am using Windows 10 64-bit and Office 2016 32-bit. The installer did not even give me a choice to install 32 or 64-bit version. It just decided to install a 32-bit version. Side question, is it worth reinstalling the 64 bit version?

[image: Outlook 2016 New Email Window]

Comment: What **exactly**  is wrong? It's not obvious from your image.

Comment: Shouldn't the text boxes on the right have the same height as the buttons (From, To, Cc) on the left?

Comment: No, I don't think so. See http://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/650x528x16_change_permissions_on_attachment.png.pagespeed.gp+jp+jw+pj+js+rj+rp+rw+ri+cp+md.ic.49iTJV7h9L.png for an example ...

Comment: Ah, ok thanks. Do you know if the font size in those text boxes define the height of the text box and is there an option to change the font size?